# Generate nice kable style tables with haven labelled data

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a dataset imported from a *.sav file. As I read this file with the *haven* package, their factors are in the "have labelled" class. I'm knitting a report in rmarkdown and want some summary tibbles to be displayed in a more fancier way with *kable* and *kableextra*.

The type of knitted chunk looks like this.

```
modelo %>%  
    group_by(AREA_RESIDENCIA) %>% 
    summarise(proportion = survey_mean(DBT))
```

The output once knitted looks like this.

```
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   AREA_RESIDENCIA proportion proportion_se
##         <dbl+lbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
## 1       1 [Urban]     0.0299       0.00211
## 2       2 [Rural]     0.0137       0.00171
```

I like that the label is shown in the tibble. I wonder if there is a way of knitting this tibble to a kable or kable extra format and still display the value labels, I can't find how. Of course I'm not taking into account reformatting the values to its labels, I would like to keep the variables as *haven labelled* and knit them in a fancy or nice html table.

Comment: I am also hoping to find this.  Surprised no one has responded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find the solution to my problem a while ago. I just needed to use the *sjlabelled* package. With that package, using the as_character function, the solution for the initial question would look like this:

```
library(sjlabelled)
modelo %>%  
    group_by(as_character(AREA_RESIDENCIA)) %>% 
    summarise(proportion = survey_mean(DBT))
```